# ISO C++ forbids declaration of “parameter” with no type

Tags: c++

I have a simple function, but it outputs the above error on compile. I looked at similar posts, but I have included the type in my declaration correctly as far as I can see. Am I just missing something simple here?

Header:

```
int LinearSearch (const vector <Die> & searchVector, const <Die> & targetVal);
```

Implementation:

```
int Game::LinearSearch (const vector <Die> & searchVector, const <Die> & targetVal) {
    // Simple linear search function which will return the index of targetVal in the vector
    // Returns null if the value isn't found
    for (int i=0; i < searchVector.size(); i++) {
        if (targetVal.pips == searchVector[i].pips) return i;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `const <Die>`???

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question. We can't tell which parameter it's complaining about, or whether the error is on the declaration or the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle brackets on the second parameter are wrong, since they are not being used to specialize a templated class like in the first parameter (`std::vector<Die>` is a specialization of the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) templated class), so you need to remove them in the second parameter.

Also, you cannot return `nullptr` as an `int`, and even if you could it would be wrong to do so.  Your loop returns the index of the matching element in the `vector`, so `nullptr` could be mistaken for index 0.  A more appropriate value to return when no match is found would be -1 instead.

```
int LinearSearch (const vector<Die> &searchVector, const Die &targetVal);
```

```
int Game::LinearSearch (const vector<Die> &searchVector, const Die &targetVal) {
    // Simple linear search function which will return the index of targetVal in the vector
    // Returns -1 if the value isn't found
    for (int i=0; i < searchVector.size(); i++) {
        if (targetVal.pips == searchVector[i].pips) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That being said, you should have a look at the [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) standard algorithm function.

Comment: A little rearrangement of whitespace would better illustrate that the angle brackets are part of the template type, and not the element type.

Comment: Thank you! That was really obvious, I think I just need to go to sleep for tonight. Also, thanks for the tip on returning the null pointer.

Comment: Hum... is every instantiation really a specialisation?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet yes, it is. Because you have to specify the template parameters in order to instantiate it.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet consider this: `vector<int> v1{1,2,3};` `vector<int> v2{1,2,3};` `vector<float> v3{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};` now consider this: `if ( v1 == v2 ) { do some work; }` okay this is valid, now try this `if ( v1 == v3 ) { do something else; }` this generates a compiler error; C2678: binary ==: no operator found... in MSVS. So I can agree with Remy Lebeau on this one.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I don't follow. How does the incompatibility of `vector<int>` vs `vector<float>` prove anything about terminology?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet When you are using the std namespace to create containers, you have to give it a type either it be a default type or a custom defined user class type or struct type to instantiate the object. Now this isn't exactly the same as when you are writing a class template where you have to write out or create a specialization or a partial specialization, however behind the scenes this is basically what is happening during compile time where the compiler is trying to deduce the type that the standard template library is trying to create. It will create a class instance of that type.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: So? I know a template is instantiated to produce a type (and this is a matter of semantics, not of implementation details within the compiler). That doesn't mean it's strictly the same as a specialisation. Back to the topic, I _had_ heard before that all instantiations count as specialisations, but it's frustrating because in my mind it makes more sense if "specialisation" is reserved for when you actually, y'know, write out and define a template specialisation so that for `T1` the behaviour is different than it is for `T2`.